# C# pointer to unmanaged struct with array

Tags: c#, pointers, data-structures, interop, unmanaged

I am trying to implement a C style struct in C# for interoperability.

Here is the struct I'm trying to convert:

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8  TrafficClass0:4;
    UINT8  Version:4;
    UINT8  FlowLabel0:4;
    UINT8  TrafficClass1:4;
    UINT16 FlowLabel1;
    UINT16 Length;
    UINT8  NextHdr;
    UINT8  HopLimit;
    UINT32 SrcAddr[4];
    UINT32 DstAddr[4];
} DIVERT_IPV6HDR, *PDIVERT_IPV6HDR;
```

And here is my C# struct:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DivertIPv6Header
{
    /// TrafficClass0 : 4
    /// Version : 4
    /// FlowLabel0 : 4
    /// TrafficClass1 : 4
    public uint bitvector1;

    /// UINT16->unsigned short
    public ushort FlowLabel1;

    /// UINT16->unsigned short
    public ushort Length;

    /// UINT8->unsigned char
    public byte NextHdr;

    /// UINT8->unsigned char
    public byte HopLimit;

    /// UINT32[4]
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint[] SrcAddr;

    /// UINT32[4]
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint[] DstAddr;

    public uint TrafficClass0
    {
        get
        {
            return bitvector1 & 15u;
        }
        set
        {
            bitvector1 = value | bitvector1;
        }
    }

    public uint Version
    {
        get
        {
            return (bitvector1 & 240u) / 16;
        }
        set
        {
            bitvector1 = (value * 16) | bitvector1;
        }
    }

    public uint FlowLabel0
    {
        get
        {
            return (bitvector1 & 3840u) / 256;
        }
        set
        {
            bitvector1 = (value * 256) | bitvector1;
        }
    }

    public uint TrafficClass1
    {
        get
        {
            return (bitvector1 & 61440u) / 4096;
        }
        set
        {
            bitvector1 = (value * 4096) | bitvector1;
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem here is that I need to declare a pointer to this structure so that I can overlap with it's data.

If I try to declare a pointer I got this compile-time error:

```
cannot declare pointer to non-unmanaged type.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Very unlikely you need a pointer, but you didn't give enough info.  "Overlap" suggests that you actually want to declare a union, you do that with the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] attribute.  But that still is a problem with the array members, for the same reason you cannot declare a pointer to this struct, you'll need to declare them as fixed size buffers with the *fixed* keyword.

Comment: I am not interested in unions. I have a pointer to a byte* array and I want to cast it to DivertIPv6Header*.

Comment: That's Marshal.PtrToStructure(), works fine without using *fixed*.  You are not helping us help you by being so vague about your requirements.

Comment: You have a pointer to an array of byte pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`:

```
        var bytes = yourUnmanagedByteArray;

        fixed (byte* b = bytes)
            return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(b), typeof(DivertIPv6Header));
```

You could make it work without a `fixed` buffer too, if you don't want to use `unsafe` code.