# Serializing / Marshalling simple objects in C# to send over network, for an unmanaged C++ application to read

Tags: c#, c++, c, serialization, marshalling

I am writing a C# application that needs to communicate with a unmanaged C++ application over the network using pre-defined messages. Every message starts with a message id and length.

```
Byte 0  MessageId
Byte 1  Length
```

After that, it is different for each message. Such as a message to set the time, will be

```
Byte 0      MessageId
Byte 1      Length
Byte 2..5   Time
```

Starting out, I figured I would just create a base class which all other messages would inherit from, which would have a method to "serialize" it:

```
public class BaseMessage
{
    public virtual byte MessageId { get; }
    public virtual byte Length { get; }

    public byte[] GetAsMessage()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SetTimeMessage : BaseMessage
{
    public override byte MessageId => 1;
    public override byte Length {get; private set; }
    public byte[] Time {get; private set; }

    public SetTimeMessage(byte[] time)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the C++ code, if I create a `SetTimeMessage` and want to send it over the network, a method like `GetAsMessage` which is defined on the base class is called, which will simply copy the contents of the object into a buffer. This works for all derived types of `BaseMessage`.

How can I do something similar in C#? I tried using the `[Serializable]` attribute and the `BinaryFormatter`, but it returned a huge byte array, not just the 6 bytes that the values actually contain.

I also looked into `Marshalling`, but it only seems to work with structs? If so, it seems like a lot of work needs to be done for each message type, since structs don't support inheritance (there are many messages I need to implement).

I will also receive messages back in the same format, which need to be deserialized back to an object. Anybody know of a neat way of achieving what I'm after?

**Edit**

I've done some experimenting with structs and marshalling, after input from Spo1ler.

Doing it this way, It's simple to serialize any message to a byte array

```
public interface IMsg
{
    byte MessageId { get; }
    byte Length { get; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SetTime: IMsg
{
    public byte Id { get; }
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Time;

    public StartLoggerWithSampleInterval(byte time)
    {
        Id = (byte) MessageType.SetTime;
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

I then have this static class to serialize the messages:

```
public static class MessageSerializer
{
    public static byte[] Serialize(IMsg msg)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(msg);
        byte[] serialized = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(msg, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, serialized, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return serialized;
    }
}
```

Initially this seems to be working like I want. Any problems that can show up doing it this way?

However, the deserialization of the messages will be a pain to write, though the first byte in the message (MessageId) should tell me what type of struct the byte array translates to

Comment: Maybe that will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17502852/1922748

Comment: that answer has nothing to do with his question ...

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryFormatter` saves the struct in a format that can be later read back again by .NET, it saves from which assembly the type came and so on and so forth, so it isn't useful in your case when you have a known byte structure of the message.

To have a structure that you can successfully serialize like Plain Old Data, you need to use `StructLayoutAttribute` on your struct like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class Message
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte MessageId;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte Length;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public byte[] Data;
}
```

`StructLayoutAttribute` with any other parameter then `LayoutKind.Auto` tells compiler to not change the layout of the structure in memory, but rather use the layout you provided. In this case, `Explicit` layout where you manually tell the offsets of the fields.

Also you should probably consider changing the message format, because having `FieldOffset`s that aren't the size of machine word can be quite expensive in terms of performance, because computers work much better with data that is aligned by the size of machine word, rather then arbitrary amount of byts.

It's a bad approach to try and build hierarchy using base classes in this manner, if you really want a hierarchy in yout message types, better use interfaces, but you still need to layout your data properly.

Then you can use marshaling to serialize your data to `byte` array, something like this

```
byte[] GetBytes(Message message) {
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(message);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(message, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return arr;
}
```

And if you want to deserialize, then you need a method like this

```
Message FromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    Message message = new Message();

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(message);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

    message = (Message)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, message.GetType());
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return message;
}
```

If you need to decide at runtime which class to use according to the message you've recieved, every one of these methods can become quite big and it's very specific to your hierarchy, but you can certainly do it by looking at first bytes and then deciding how to deserialize them accordingly.

But from my point of view it's a bad approach to try and do hierarchy based on some common parts of the message. You'd rather do some sequences of message of known types to distinct which message you will get next or something like this, but it's up to you. The information that I have provided here should be enough to serialize any integral type to array of bytes which you can later send over the network.

Comment: that is no answer at all since he wants to DESERIALIZE CLASSES OUT OF NETWORK PACKETS

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can the structs be serialized to a byte array in a generic way, if they all implement the same interface? So instead of having a GetBytes and FromBytes on each and single struct, I have a static function which can take a struct that implements IMessage?

Comment: Well, you can, but not in the way described above. You would need to manually construct the array, because .NET serialisation isn't suitable for the task like this in a generic way. It's a big task and I'm sure that it's suitable for stack overflow answer, but I can give you some general directions on how to implement it.

Comment: Fwiw, using Pack = 1 is enough to avoid having to use [FieldOffset].  It is however not very likely that the C++ code is using it, it defaults to Pack = 8.  Getting this to match is important.  The hazard of not using something like Protobuf.

Comment: Yeah, this protocol was defined a long time ago, and saving bytes in the message was and still is more important than having something that is easy to work with. Wish I could use something like protobuf :)